# How do I prevent logs from being truncated?

Tags: anchor, logs

```
    'Program log: Instruction: PositionSwap',
    'Program log: a_to_b: true',
    'Program log: amount: 0',
    ... 15 more items
  ],
  programErrorStack: ProgramErrorStack { stack: [ [PublicKey], [PublicKey] ] }
}
```

I'd **really** like to know what those `... 15 more items` are..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple fix:

```
} catch (e){
  console.log(e)
}
```

```
} catch (e){
  console.log(e.logs.slice(-50))
}
```

Comment: consider annotating the code to help future users better understand how this solution answers the question